# Calling cURL command from C++ returns unexpected error codes like 1792 and 6656

Tags: c++, linux, curl, endianness

I have a C++ application running on an embedded Linux that builds and calls cURL commands to copy files to an FTP server.

```
std::string cmd = "curl --connect-timeout 10 --ftp-create-dirs "
                  + localPath + filename + " "
                  + ftpPath + filename + " "
                  + userAuth;

int retVal = system(cmd.c_str());
```

Depending on the variables to build the command, this returns unexpected error codes. For example, when I try to copy a file that doesn't exist, `retVal` is 6656 instead of the expected 26 ("local file not found"), and when I turn off the server, `retVal` is 1792 instead of the expected 7 ("could not connect to server").

Looking at the values, I am pretty sure that this has something to do with endianness, but I would like to understand the root cause. The device has an ARMv7 processor and uses little endian format.

Comment: 1792 seems to be 7 in the other endian, so that is possibly the case.

Comment: @Chipster And similarly `26 = 0x1A`, `6656 = 0x1A00`.

Comment: @Botje Actually it does, I just didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with endianness, but is documented in the `system` manpage:

> In the last two cases, the return value is a "wait status" that can  be
>          examined using the macros described in waitpid(2).  (i.e., WIFEXITED(),
>          WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).

and `WEXITSTATUS`:

> WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
>                 returns the exit status of the  child.
>      This  consists  of  the
>                 least  significant  8 bits of the status argument that the child
>                 specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or  as  the  argument
>                 for a return statement in main().
>   This macro should be employed
>                 only if WIFEXITED returned true.

If you just want to know if the command succeeded, you should use:

```
if (WIFEXITED(retVal)) {
   int retCode = WIFEXITSTATUS(retVal);
   ...
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(retVal) {
   int signal = WTERMSIG(retVal);
   ...
} else {
   /* process was stopped by a signal */
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Seems like I looked into the wrong direction and it's not actually a curl problem. So if I want to check for specific error codes, I could do something like `switch (WEXITSTATUS(retVal)) { case 7: ... }` ?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you check for `WIFEXITED(retVal)` first.